# How to disable two factor authentication in GitHub?

Tags: github

How to log in my GitHub account without typing identification numbers sent from GitHub? They always send my old email address which I no longer use. So, I’ve been stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the button for disabling is hidden under these three points in the figure below...they are barely visible...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, **you can't.** To disable 2FA authentication requires that you enable 2FA Authentication first (using your *personal phone*), which is absolutely something you *do not want to ever do* with any Microsoft service.  This is a company that has regularly and continually done everything *insecure* almost on purpose: from [the deliberately faulty MS-CHAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-CHAP), to [the widespread adoption of Java when it was deemed a security flaw by the US Dept of Homeland security](https://www.zdnet.com/article/homeland-security-warns-java-still-poses-risks-after-security-fix/), to the particularly recent [Microsoft Bitlocker being hacked by a $30 raspberry pi](https://readwrite.com/microsoft-bitlocker-encryption-hacked-by-a-cheap-off-the-shelf-raspberry-pi-pico/#:%7E:text=Data%20and%20Security-,Microsoft%20BitLocker%20encryption%20hacked%20by%20a%20cheap,the%2Dshelf%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Pico&text=Security%20researcher%20Stacksmashing%20showed%20how,seconds%2C%20in%20a%20YouTube%20video.).

Microsoft simply DOES NOT CARE about your security or your privacy.  And all of the people who have been calling the shots over there have faced virtually no reprecussions for their actions.

If you need a way to store a repo that doesn't require you handing over extremely important personal information, **DON'T USE GITHUB.**  Suggested alternatives:

- GitLab
- GitTea
- SourceForge